# Error in fetching value using openpyxl and python

Tags: python-3.x, excel-formula, openpyxl

There are two values for this code: G82's value is 15,000 and its formula is =Assumptions!E32. When I fetch value for G82, instead of 15,000 the value which is shown is =Assumptions!E32. Any other method or function which I should use. Is there any mistake in my code.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

aa = load_workbook('H2.xlsx')
ab = 'Sheet1'            #Sheet1's name
ab1 = "Assumptions"      #Sheet: "Assumption"

print(b['G82'].value


#Answer is =Assumptions!E32 instead of 15,000
```

Comment: This is covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been asked many times and is covered in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark. I saw your answers, they helped. Have a nice one

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from available answers by Charlie clark and others. Its about changing how the file is read by additionally specifying the same. It will open all the formulas as values hence the said issues will be resolved.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

aa = load_workbook('H2.xlsx',data_only = True )  #only difference is in this line
ab = 'Sheet1'            #Sheet1's name
ab1 = "Assumptions"      #Sheet: "Assumption"

print(b['G82'].value
```

This changes would give the needed output.
For the application I was writing this code, I also wanted the formulas as well as their immediate outputs (and not what the refer to) so I imported the workbook twice with different names, normally the first time and other time as ` = True.
So wherever I needed use of formulas I will call out the normal one and on needing the values would call the later.